# Windows DNS stops working after power failure

Tags: windows, windows-10, dns, internet-connection

I never had this issue before but in my new home, from time to time I experience power failures while working on my computer. After restarting my Internet Connection is no longer working on that computer, but the rest of the devices are able to use the same Internet connection just fine.

I know it's a DNS issue for sure because if I ping a url it fails but if I use the IP instead the ping responds.

I have tried flushing the DNS as well as resetting the internet connection, even system restore to no avail. The only way to get the computer online y to reinstall or do a factory reset which is a pain as this issue happens quite often.

At first I was suspencting it was hardware related but it also happened on different computers a few times. It all seems related to a power interruption though once the computer froze and when I rebooted I had this same issue.

Even though this never happened to me prior to the power problems I see there are a lot of people experiencing this problem on the Internet and in different windows versions. I have win 10 in all my computers but I see people having the same issue with Win 7, 8 and 8.1

Any ideas? this just happened to me once again and I would like to avoid having to spend a complete day reinstalling all the stuff.

Comment: When the problem occurs can you ping your DNS server? Can you use nslookup to perform queries against it?

Comment: Yes I can ping and do a nslookup against the DNS server which is the router at 192.168.1.1

Comment: Then why do you think it's a DNS issue?

Comment: Because it's unable to resolve urls. I am unable to ping www,google.com but I can ping it's ip [172.217.28.196] The troubleshooter also mentions a DNS issue but doen's offer options for fixing it. If I put the ip in the browser it forwards to google.com and fails to load

Comment: So you can't ping by DNS hostname but you can resolve DNS hostnames with nslookup? Can you ping by hostname *after* resolving with nslookup?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, nslookup works but I can't ping by domain name. I have tried the usual solutions:   ipconfig /flushdns ---

netsh winsock reset ---

netsh int ip reset resettcpip.txt

Comment: What else is losing power? It's unlikely that your PC losing power would make it permanently unable to resolve hostnames.

Comment: Try to set your computer's DNS server to [Google Public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/), to see if the problem is with the router's DNS.

Comment: Google's DNS doesn't workt either. I know it sounds strange, but it's like that. I also have linux on the same machine, no problem at all navigating the internet. I know it sounds strange but if you google it you will find many people having the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: for me it's caused by VPN (setup by OpenVPN in my case) DNS routing policy leftover on power loss. Had to manually remove the registry to fix it.

Long story: I have the exact same problem with this Windows 10 laptop I have (battery disconnected, but that's another story as to why). After losing power, DNS will just stop working. The internet connection is actually fine though and I can ping/connect to other hosts using IP. Apps in WSL also work properly with DNS lookup. The problem applies to both wired and wireless network.

I managed to track down the problem by firing up wireshark, which I instantly see lots of dns requests sent to an IP that is not valid in my local network. I then search for this IP in regedit and I found it appeared under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\Dnscache\Parameters\DnsPolicyConfig\OpenVPNDNSRouting-0
```

and

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}
```

At this point it is clear that it was some DNS policy setup by my VPN. I backed up both keys just in case and then deleted them in the registry and DNS works again right away.

So the full picture is I have OpenVPN up before the power loss. It has some DNS routing policy so private network hostnames lookup will go via a DNS server over the VPN. At a power loss, obviously OpenVPN isn't able to shutdown and unregister this policy. Then when the system is back up, the DNS routing policy is still enabled while the VPN is actually not up yet, as it cannot connect back to the VPN since it tries to connect to the VPN gateway using hostname not IP.

Comment: Thank you!!!! that was the problem. Symply removing the first entry fixed the internet connection