# Windows 10 DNS/Networking broken after losing power while connected to OpenVPN

Tags: networking, windows-10, openvpn

While connected to an OpenVPN network, my computer lost power. After restarting, I can connect to my wireless network but it says "No internet access". I can ping 8.8.8.8, but trying to ping www.google.com just hangs. ipconfig also hangs-it prints "Windows IP Configuration" and stops. I can't see the properties of any of my network adaptors either-they seem to just hang-and it looks like any sort of DNS request is hanging as well. I've tried disabling various and all network adaptors, without any change in ipconfig, etc. The built-in network diagnostics generally hangs as well at "starting diagnostics".

I tried rebooting in safe mode, and I can run ipconfig and examine the properties of adaptors but I still am not able to use DNS or connect to the network. I've manually set the dns for both IPv4 and IPv6, with no improvement out of safe mode. I've run sfc and dism, both of which claim everything's good. I uninstalled and reinstalled OpenVPN without success, and tried to reconnect to the VPN network I was on before losing power, which failed at getting an IP from the network and didn't resolve anything.

I'm running out of ideas, anyone have any suggestions?

Running Windows 10 Home, on the Insider slow ring.

Edit: This looks similar but not quite the same: [Windows DNS stops working after power failure](https://superuser.com/questions/1448497/windows-dns-stops-working-after-power-failure). Should someone come here in the future with the same issue, try those steps as well

Comment: Try running DISM from an admin command prompt: dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  . Then run SFC /SCANNOW.  Restart and test. If that fails run a Windows Repair Install from the Windows 10 Media Creation Link

Comment: @John I've done the first two already, will try the last tonight.

Comment: So then do the repair install to see if that corrects the error. Try first with Keep Everything to see if that works

Comment: Another to try in CMD is `netsh winsock reset` then restart the PC after its completed.

Comment: @CraftyB Tried that, no luck.

Comment: @John Looks like I'm running an Insider Preview, which I can't seem to find installation media for. The latest I've found on Microsoft's website still appears to be older than my Slow Ring install. I can't repair, can only wipe and start over. Really don't want to do that...

Comment: There is no Repair for Windows Insider (I do have a machine with the most recent Insider running).  So if DISM, SFC and Winsock repairs do not work, you may have to install a production version of Windows 10.

Comment: Ouch. That sucks. Barring someone else having seen and dealt with something like this before, it looks like I may be out of luck.

Comment: Insider requirements are that no critical information be retained on the machine and it no be  production machine. Yes, bad news, but this is all you can do for a proper and long term repair

Comment: @John Put all that in an answer, and I'll accept it. Barring someone showing up with a miracle solution, that's all we can do. FYI, I've done a reset already and the problem is solved, at the cost of installed programs, etc.

Comment: There is now an answer for you. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try try running DISM from an admin command prompt: dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth . Then run SFC /SCANNOW. Restart and test.

If that fails run a Windows Repair Install from the Windows 10 Media Creation Link

However you noted during the comments that you are using Windows Insider.

Insider requirements are that no critical information be retained on the machine and it no be production machine. Yes, bad news, but all you can do for a proper and long term repair is to reinstall Windows.

I hope this helps you.